Do quantum particles have classical trajectories or are they in superposition when falling through the event horizon?
I have read this question:
If free electrons have classical trajectories, then why don't bound electrons around the nuclei have it too?
Where @AcuriousMind says:

Free electrons do not "have" classical trajectories any more than bound ones do.

Now we do know that the event horizon is not an object, rather it is a boundary between two regions of spacetime. Now if quantum particles do not have classical trajectories, then what happens in the moment they "pass" the event horizon?
Naively thinking, in a "classical" view, the particles just "fly" straight through the boundary that we call event horizon, and there is a classically well defined moment or event when and how this happens. I can always separate two events, first, the classical trajectory shows the particle being outside, and the next event is inside, and these two can be distinguished. There is no superposition.
However, quantum particles do not have this kind of classical trajectories, and they do not have a size (spatial extent), they are point like. They are allowed to be in a superposition of being inside and outside the event horizon.
So now we have a quite different picture, a point particle, passing through a boundary (event horizon) without the notion of a classical trajectory (like flying straight through). This particle is supposed to be in a superposition of both inside and outside the horizon which could be impossible because nothing can leave from inside, that is, once the particle is in superposition of being inside and outside, it cannot be just outside anymore. It might be that the solution is that it smoothly changes from being in a superposition into being just inside. But the question remains, how is this possible?
Question:

Do quantum particles have classical trajectories or are they in superposition when falling through the event horizon?


We cannot ever observe the particles falling through the event horizon. Do you mean in an observer's local frame? In that case, how is it different from when the particles are at rest?

@controlgroup yes I mean in an observer's local frame, but the particles are never at rest, since they are quantum particles in superposition. I'm not sure why the downvote.

The downvote is not mine - I suspect, though, that it is likely due to the fact that considering what happens to quantum particles near an event horizon requires a theory of quantum gravity that we don't have.

The horizon “is a boundary between two regions of spacetime”, not of space, as implied in your question. The horizon and inside are separated in time, not in space. Once you are close enough, the horizon is not a surface you cross, but more like a moment of time you wait for to happen, and it happens everywhere around you simultaneously. For example, if you fall feet forward, then your feet and your head cross the horizon at the same time. Therefore there is no issue for a particle to be in a superposition while crossing the horizon, same as crossing the moment of midnight into tomorrow +1.

@safesphere perfect answer thank you! This is what I was thinking about. Maybe you could put this as an answer, I could accept it.  "not of space, as implied in your question.", can you please tell me how should I change the title to fix it?

The title is fine. The issue is with this statement: “They are allowed to be in a superposition of being inside and outside the event horizon” - This statement implies that inside and outside are separated by space, but they are separated by time. Rigorously, no external event is in the future light cone of any event at the horizon or inside. In a normal human language this means that anything at the horizon or inside happens after everything outside. Here “after” implies separation in time. Thus your question is based on an incorrect premise.

My comment only addresses a flaw in your question about the superposition, but does not provide an answer, because only the theory of quantum gravity can tell us what actually happens at the horizon. For example the delayed choice experiment shows that quantum particles can be entangled while separated by time. This means that a particle we have here and now can be entangled with another that will cross the horizon in the infinite future. What this implies is unclear. Physicists theorize, but they don’t really have any clue without proper quantum gravity.

@safesphere "anything at the horizon or inside happens after everything outside. " Are you claiming there is an overarching universal time? If not, how can you make sense of the terms "before" and "after?"

@D.Halsey (1) You quote the explanation of the statement. Please read the actual statement in the previous sentence starting with “Rigorously”. It is exact and coordinate independent. Intuitively it means what you quoted. (2) The sequence of events, like “after” or “before”, is defined by causality, which is defined by the global hyperbolicity of the Schwarzschild spacetime. (3) Relativity of simultaneity doesn’t always apply. For example, if you have two remote flashlights where the first is triggered by the light of the second, then in any coordinates the first flashes after the second.

@D.Halsey Visually, consider first the Minkowski diagram: https://tikz.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/relativity_penrose_diagram-003.png - Note that horizontal curved lines are of equal time. Both upper angled borders represent cosmological eternity. Everything in the universe happens before anything on these borders. Now compare to the black hole diagram: https://tikz.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/relativity_penrose_diagram-007.png - and notice that the above conclusion has not changed. The upper left angled line still is the cosmological eternity, even though it now represents the horizon.
